# Getting Wrong ancestor for the right side of the tree

Tags: python, tree, binary, binary-tree, least-common-ancestor

So I was trying to implement LCA using Euler tour and RMQ with Sparse Table in python. My code is working fine, if I insert number from left side of the tree. The code for building the tree is:

The node class has data, left_child and right_child:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.data = value
        self.right_child = None
        self.left_child = None
```

Then I have a tree class which I used to build the tree:

```
class Tree:
    content = []
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        
    def add_child(self, arr, root, i, n):
        if i < n:
            temp = Node(arr[i])
            root = temp
            
            root.left_child = self.add_child(arr, root.left_child, 2 * i + 1, n)
            root.right_child = self.add_child(arr, root.right_child, 2 * i + 2, n)
            
        return root
    
    def pre_order(self, root):
        
        if root != None:
            Tree.content.append(root.data)
            self.pre_order(root.left_child)
            self.pre_order(root.right_child)
            
        return Tree.content
```

Finally, I got an LCA class which mainly contains the function for building the sparse table, then do a RMQ on the sparse table, then a function that does the part of the euler tour and finally the function for finding LCA.

```
class LCA:
    
    def __init__(self, root, length):
        self.pre_process_array = [[0] * (math.floor(math.log2(length) + 2)) for _ in range((length * 2) - 1)]
        self.euler = [0] * (length * 2 - 1)
        self.height = [0] * (length * 2 - 1)
        self.index = [-1  for _ in range(length + 1)]
        self.tour = 0
        
        self.euler_tour(root, 0)
        self.build_sparse_table(self.height)
        
        print(self.pre_process_array)
        
    def build_sparse_table(self, height_array):
        for i in range(len(height_array)):
            self.pre_process_array[i][0] = height_array[i]
            
        j = 1
        
        while (1 << j) <= len(height_array):
            
            i = 0
            while (i + (1 << j) - 1) < len(height_array):
                
                if self.pre_process_array[i][j - 1] < self.pre_process_array[i + (1 << (j - 1))][j-1]:
                    self.pre_process_array[i][j] = self.pre_process_array[i][j - 1]
                else:
                    self.pre_process_array[i][j] = self.pre_process_array[i + (1 << (j - 1))][j - 1]
                    
                i += 1
            
            j += 1
            
    def rmq(self, l, h):
        j = int(math.log2(h - l + 1))
        
        if self.pre_process_array[l][j] <= self.pre_process_array[h - (1 << j) + 1][j]:
            return self.pre_process_array[l][j]
        else:
            return self.pre_process_array[h - (1 << j) + 1][j]
        
    def euler_tour(self, root, level):
        if root is not None:

            self.euler[self.tour] = root.data
            self.height[self.tour] = level
            self.tour += 1
            
            if self.index[root.data] == -1:
                self.index[root.data] = self.tour - 1
                
            if root.left_child is not None:
                self.euler_tour(root.left_child, level + 1)
                self.euler[self.tour] = root.data
                self.height[self.tour] = level
                self.tour += 1
                
            if root.right_child is not None:
                self.euler_tour(root.right_child, level + 1)
                self.euler[self.tour] = root.data
                self.height[self.tour] = level
                self.tour += 1
            
    def find_LCA(self, val1, val2):
        if val1 >= len(self.index) or val2 >= len(self.index) or self.index[val1] == -1 or self.index[val2] == -1:
            return -1
        
        if self.index[val1] > self.index[val2]:
            return self.euler[self.rmq(self.index[val2], self.index[val1])]
        elif self.index[val2] > self.index[val1]:
            return self.euler[self.rmq(self.index[val1], self.index[val2])]
```

And my driver code is as follow:

```
tree_data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
length = len(tree_data)
         
tree = Tree()
root = tree.root

tree.root = tree.add_child(tree_data, root, 0, length)
l = LCA(tree.root, length)

print(l.find_LCA(6, 3))
```

so, my tree should something look like:

```
                               1
                             /   \
                            2     3
                           / \   / \
                          4   5  6  7
                         / \
                        8   9
```

Now, if I try to find the LCA(8, 9) or LCA(4, 3), I get the correct output but whenever I try to give LCA(6, 7) or LCA(3, 7), It always keeps returning 2 as the answer where it should return 3 and 3 respectively.

I don't have any idea where is the mistake as, from my side it looks pretty fine.

Comment: Add the exact error to your post (use [Edit]).

Comment: This is an elaborate question, which is fine, but it asks some effort from anyone that is going to take it on. Since you haven't accepted an answer on your previous question, the motivation may be lacking with those who might otherwise spend their time on this though.

Comment: Hi Andro, could you please accept an answer for your previous question? It can give SO users an incentive to spend time on your other questions as well.